# Is the a way to retrieve all of the comments my page was tagged in through the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging

I see that there is a way to retrieve the public posts where my Page has been tagged through the Facebook Graph API.  Is there also a way to retrieve public comments that tag my Page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed  Not possible for comments though, AFAIK.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I was reading that documentation.  I didn't see anywhere in the API docs that it specifically mentioned that retrieving tagged comments is not supported - thus my question.  I am currently assuming that it's not supported.